# By making API calls in Angular (8) trying to get the count match with the data

Tags: angular, rest

It might seem stupid to some but most of my confusion is caused by my frustration.

I am making API calls to some endpoints from this page: https://beacon-network.org/#/developers/api/beacon-network#bn-beacons

I have no problem at the service I am able to get the data. My service.ts:

```
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {Organization} from './organization'; // it is an interface that has id and name
import {Beacons} from './beacons'; // it is an interface that has id and name

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class BeaconService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  public fetchOrganizations(): Observable<Organization[]> {
    return this.http.get<Organization[]>('https://beacon-network.org/api/organizations');
  }

  public fetchBeacons(): Observable<Beacons[]> {
    return this.http.get<Beacons[]>('https://beacon-network.org/api/beacons');
  
}
```

This is my component.html

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="organizations$"
       class="mat-elevation-z8">

  <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>ID</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.id}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Name</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="beacons">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Beacons</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{beaconCount}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

This gives me a table of ID, Name and Beacons. ID and Name are matched correctly. My problem is that beacons(beacon count) should have different numbers with the right match of the company name, I checked this with Postman and as an example Wellcome Trust Sanger Institute should return 5. According to what name I get I get 1, 2, 5 or 0 for all. Some outputs should be 21, 5, 4 etc.

Finally this is my component.ts:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable, Subscription} from 'rxjs';
import {BeaconService} from './beacon.service';
import {Organization} from './organization';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-beacon',
  templateUrl: './beacon.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./beacon.component.css']
})
export class BeaconComponent implements OnInit {

  organizations$: Observable<Organization[]>;
  beacon: any = {};
  displayedColumns = ['id', 'name', 'beacons'];

  organizations: Array<any>;

  organizationId: string;
  organizationName: string;
  beaconData: any = {};
  beacons: Array<any>;

  beaconCount = 0;
  organizationNameArray: Array<any> = [];


  constructor(private beaconService: BeaconService) {
    this.organizations$ = this.beaconService.fetchOrganizations();
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.beaconService.fetchOrganizations().subscribe((organizationData) => {
      this.organizations = organizationData;
      for (let i = 0; i < this.organizations.length; i++) {
        this.organizationId = this.organizations[i].id;
        this.organizationName = this.organizations[i].name;
        this.organizationNameArray.push(this.organizationName);
      }
      return this.organizationNameArray;
    });

    this.beaconService.fetchBeacons().subscribe(beacons => {
      let organizationNameInBeacon;
      this.beacons = beacons;
      for (const beacon of this.beacons) {
        this.beaconCount = 0;
        for (const org of this.organizations) {
          if (beacon.organization === org.name) {
            organizationNameInBeacon = beacon.organization;
            this.beaconCount++;
          }
        }
      }
      return this.beaconCount;
    });
  }
}
```

My output should be the name of the organization and the right beacon count for that. I need help here.

Response summary should be something like:
Found: 6, Not Found: 39, Not Applicable:36

Comment: You are using the same `beaconCount` in all rows. How can you expect it to show the right value in each row?

Comment: Please show me what you actually see in the table (screenshot). Ideally create a reproducible app in Stackblitz.

Comment: @Benny I know but I confused myself a lot and I don't know how to fix it now. I think what I am doing with my nested for loops is not wrong but I couldn't achieve what I actually want. Can you point me in the right direction or better yet write a solution please?

Comment: @Benny Updated the question with a screenshot of my result

Comment: You should have a list of beacon counts, each associated with a single organization. Something like `beaconCounts: KeyValue<string, number>`. In the loop update the right entry, and then in the html show `beaconCounts[element.name]`. I can help change your code if you set up a Stackblitz app with your code in it.

Comment: @Benny are you able to access and edit it?

Comment: Please change the service to get only the first 100 of each API call. It takes forever to load because there are a ton of organizations/beacons. (When the console is open)

Comment: @Benny Changed it, it is done. I see considerable less on the console now

Comment: @Benny I limited it with 25, 100 was still a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just fork join the to response and then match them together and just use that observable for binding.

```
export class BeaconComponent implements OnInit {
  displayedColumns = ['id', 'name', 'beacons'];
  fetching:boolean
  countedBeaconOrgs$: Observable<OrganizationBecons[]>;
  constructor(private beaconService: BeaconService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.fetching = true;
    this.countedBeaconOrgs$ = forkJoin([
      this.beaconService.fetchOrganizations(),
      this.beaconService.fetchBeacons(),
    ]).pipe(
      map(([orgs, beacons]): OrganizationBecons[] => {
        const countedOrgs: OrganizationBecons[] = [];
        for (const org of orgs) {
          countedOrgs.push({
            ...org,
            beaconCount: beacons.filter((b) => b.organization == org.name)
              .length,
          });
        }
        return countedOrgs;
      }),
      tap(()=> {
          this.fetching=false;
      })
    );

  }
}
export interface OrganizationBecons extends Organization {
  beaconCount: number;
}
```

the binding

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="countedBeaconOrgs$" class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>ID</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.id }}    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Name</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.name }}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="beacons">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Beacon Count</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.beaconCount }}</td>
  </ng-container>
 <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
 <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></tr>
</table>
<h1 *ngIf="fetching">Loading</h1>
```

updated stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vjttsn?file=src%2Fbeacon%2Fbeacon.component.ts

edit: Added ugly loading to the requests.

Comment: I thought `forkJoin` was deprecated :)
Would it be hard to add a spinner on this when it is getting the data?

Comment: forkJoin only depricated when you do not parse an array. Adding a spinner you could just do a pipe tap on the `countedBeaconOrgs$` with a boolean value

Comment: updated my answer with a h1 loading tag. you probably wanna give it a style or a material spinner etc.